# Unit testing code inside TransactionSynchronizationManager

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit

I couldn't find a working solution, how to unit test something that happened inside TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(). I have code like this:

```
pubclic class MyService {
    public void method() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void afterCommit()
                            {
                                myService.callSmth(params);
                            }
                        }
    }
}
```

Here I call method():

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyService myService;

    public void method2() {
        myService.method();
    }
}
```

In my unit test I need to *verify* that myService.callSmth. But seems like test code doesn't go into afterCommit() method. 
That's my test class:

```
@Configurable
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:test-applicationContext.xml" })
public class ServiceTest extends TestHelper
{
    @Mock
    MyService myService;

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void allowWriteOffGlobal()
    {
         myClass.method();
         veryfy(myService).method();
    }
}
```

I simplified my code and please, don't pay attention if there could be any mistakes in mocking and smth like this. In a debugger I see how the flow comes to line TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization and skips the afterCommit() method. 
P.s.: not sure I provided enough info. Please, write in the comment if there is a need of smth extra. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say without more detail (seeing your test would help) but perhaps your test code doesn't commit transactions? It's common for tests running against transactional datasources to rollback on test completion thereby wiping any test data and ensuring that such tests are self contained.

Comment: I don't have @Transactional annotation on my test. This is not a guarantee that commit happen?

Comment: If you update your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you're more likely to get a specific, relevant, complete answer.

Comment: So you have a mock and you expect that it behaves like the real object as spring would create it. This will obviously not work, you should use `@MockBean` not `@Mock` and insteda of `@InjectMocks` use `@Autowired` as you want the actual configured object. Finally this hardly is a unit test but more of an integration test. Do you really need the transaction syncronization, isn't there an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Spring Test documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html) (emphasis mine):

> Annotating a test method with @Transactional causes the test to be run within ***a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test***. If a test class is annotated with @Transactional, each test method within that class hierarchy will be run within a transaction. Test methods that are not annotated with @Transactional (at the class or method level) will not be run within a transaction. Furthermore, tests that are annotated with @Transactional but have the propagation type set to NOT_SUPPORTED will not be run within a transaction.

and

> By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after completion of the test; ***however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the @Commit and @Rollback annotations*** at the class level and at the method level.

So I suggest putting a `@Commit` annotation in your test method. (By the behaviour you describe I suppose that you are using Spring Test, this advice does not apply otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` and call `afterCommit()`